# Magento2 run specific cron manually

Tags: magento2

On my env, I want to run a specific cron via cmd or programmatically.

My magento2 cron is disabled, how to make sure that this particular cron is set to queue

Comment: If you type php bin/magento cron:run --group="default" you will run cronjobs from default group. In logs you will have informations about cronjobs (if started, if finished)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using MageRun2.

1. Download from https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2

Then try the following way:

```
php n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run your_cron_name
```

Ex. you run backup cron by following way:

```
php n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run system_backup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module: https://github.com/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager

bin/magento cronmanager:killjob - Kill cron jobs by code

bin/magento cronmanager:runjob - Run a specific cron job by its job_code

bin/magento cronmanager:showjobs - Show all cron job codes in Magento

Answer (score 0):

An other way would be to use the standard cron system for linux by editing directly the crontab.

This is what i'm used to do for my projects

Ex with 2 custom command ran by cron:

```
#~ MAGENTO START xxx
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/nes-prod/www/current/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/project-prod/www/current/var/log/magento.cron.log
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php7.3 /home/project-prod/www/current/bin/magento legend:import
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php7.3 /home/project-prod/www/current/bin/magento legend:export
```

Answer (score 0):

Below script run cron class from command line
or any other class/method combination you want

In sample below, it run job: \YourVendor\YourModule\Stock\Import->execute()

```
<?php

/**
 * CLI run: php bin/magerun.php "YourVendor\YourModule\Stock\Import"
**/
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

if (!isset($argv[1])) {
    die('Please add the class of the cron job you want to execute enclosed IN DOUBLE QUOTES as a parameter.' . PHP_EOL);
} else {
    define('CRONJOBCLASS', $argv[1]);
}

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$cron = $obj->create(CRONJOBCLASS);

$cron->execute();
```